# Compiling error opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on opencv implemented codes which I downloaded already by svn. These codes such as SIFT or SURF and codes for opencv were working perfectly before, but suddenly I got this error while I want to compile any code concerns opencv

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So how can I solve it please, I have red already some problems but they were not helpful with my case, such as I have to change the compilation code from `g++ SIFT.cpp -o SIFT ....` to `g++ -o SIFT SIFT.cpp ....` but it didn't work out with me.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be difficult to help you without seeing the contents of `SIFT.cpp`.  The problem is that you're attempting to link an executable with no `main` function defined.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I just had a similar problem (with OpenCV 2.4.4a (and also 2.4.1)) and this was the first thing that popped up on google.

I disabled the "precompiled headers" option in the OpenCV configuration (do it from `cmake-gui`, or pass `-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF` to `cmake` when generating), and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`main` is the starting point of execution of any **C++** program. And you probably have forgot to build the source file that has `main` function. Since the file you built doesn't has `main`, linker failed to find the starting point of execution.

```
g++ SIFT.cpp fileThatHasMainFunctionDefinition.cpp -o SIFT
```

or alternatively provide the `main` in `SIFT.cpp` itself.

Comment: The thing is, I did compile before and it was working very well and i got nice results and these programs are implemented already not me who did that, but now i got that. What do you think is the best to do?


gcc sift.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o test
this is how I compile

Comment: @Mario - I am not aware of openCV but the linker failed to find where `main` is all I can say from the error message. Sorry.